# JPA - If a parent entity was referenced before a JPQL query fetching child objects, the parent entity is fetched in the results ignoring lazy load

Tags: java, spring, repository, jpql, lazy-evaluation

*Edited*

I have a simple uni directional @ManyToOne Lazy relationship:

> ```
> public class UserLog {
> ...
> @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
> @JoinColumn(name = "userId", updatable=false,insertable=false)
> private User user;
> ...
> }
> ```

I use lazy loading, because there are cases when I want the user field to be populated, but sometimes not. I use spring, and my app is configured with hibernate, and I use the hibernate 5 module in my configuration so my entities are only fetched in my json results when I request it.

```
@Bean
public Module hibernate5Module()
{
    return new Hibernate5Module();
}
```

So the problem is, when I want to fetch for example an user's log in this way:

```
User user = userRepository.findOne(userId);
...
/*Checking user object before requesting logs...*/
...
List<UserLog> userlogs = userLogRepository.getUserLogs(userId);

// (query looks like this: "select u from UserLog u where u.userId = ?1")
```

When I return my `userlogs` list, the user field is populated in the json response.
If I don't fetch the `user` object from the `userRepository` (commenting out the first line), then the `user` field is empty correctly.

I tested modifying my `getUserLogs` query to not make any reference to the `userId` field, but the user is still fetched.

So my question is, how can I make JPA to fetch the user field when I access it directly (e.g using `JOIN FETCH u.user` in my query)? Why is the `user` field fetched, even though I didn't access the user field in my userlog object?

I'd greatly appreciate any advice.

**Edit:** By using `entityManager.clear();` before requesting the `userlogs`, the `user` field is not populated anymore. This solution seems a bit hacky, there must be another way other than detaching the entities? Because if I want to modify the `User` object after requesting the logs, I'd have to request the `User` object again.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is quite simple:

You are asking from db a certain `User` by his id and right after a UserLog by the same `userId`.

Now after the first request hibernate is keeping the `User` in it's first level cache.

In your second request you specify lazy fetching for `User` relationship and, as you noted, it's working:

> (commenting out the first line), then the user field is empty correctly.

The point here is that hibernate already has the corresponding `User` in the cache so there is no need to query the database for it and just give it to you.

If instead you clear cache as you tried, you force hibernate to hit the db and in turn to give you just a proxy as per Lazy fetching

You should be able to verify from log that no additional query is being executed.